# Que es el soporte CORS

Tags: android, android-studio

"Could not load the manifest file. make sure the source is set correctly and cors support is enabled"
Este es el error del reproductor THEOplayer saben cual es el problema?, intente colocarle otro link y funciona correctamente, solamente da ese error cuando el enlace del stream es el que quiero mostrar.

**MainActivity.java**

```
THEOplayerView tpv;
```

....

```
  tpv = findViewById(R.id.theoplayer_view);
    tpv.getSettings().setFullScreenOrientationCoupled(true);

    SourceDescription sourceDescription = SourceDescription.Builder.sourceDescription("https://video1.getstreamhosting.com:1936/8462/8462/playlist.m3u8")
            .build();
    tpv.getPlayer().setSource(sourceDescription);
    tpv.getPlayer().setAutoplay(true);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.theoplayer.android.api.THEOplayerView
            android:id="@+id/theoplayer_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pipBtn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:background="@drawable/picture_in_picture_alt_white"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </com.theoplayer.android.api.THEOplayerView>
```

Comment: El Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) es un mecanismo de protección para que otras aplicaciones o sitios web soliciten contenido (manifests, video files or encryption keys) a otro dominio, podrías indicarnos que plataforma estas utilizando para realizar el streaming. esto es según la documentación oficial https://support.theoplayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/206932789-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing porque debes especificar si el streaming sera libre (*)  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * o especificar el dominio o IP que consumirá el recurso.

Comment: Estas usando el SDK de TheoPlayer? Agrega por favor como lo que estas tratando de realizar para que la comunidad responda a tu pregunta, saludos @ElmerYuca

Comment: la plataforma que estoy utilizando para realizar el streaming es https://getstreamhosting.com/

Comment: @Jorgesys exactamente me proporcionaron una sdk para utilizar THEOplayer